# php7 и вывод данных помогите разобраться

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Добрый день! Делаю некотрые переделки в сайте и не могу разобраться с выводом и работой такого дела как:

(в БД например столбцы text, url)

В файле конфига (напр config.php) я пишу (php 5+):

```
function Content($url){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE url='$url'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $result_page = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $result_page;
}
```

В файле вывода информации:

```
include('config.php');  
$row = Content('название_урл');
```

вывод текста `$row['text']`

Конечно я могу вывести по ID (например id=2) но у меня есть ряд задач при которых нужно оставить именно таким макаром (например корзина на аяксе так сделана)

Суть вопроса на 7php не работает и хоть тресни. 
Помогите кто в теме. Заранее спасибо

Код который не работает в 7пхп:

```
function Content($url){

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE url='$url'");
    $result_page = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result_page;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67437/discussion-on-question-by-vladislav-carley-php7-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основываясь на выложенных файлах.

1. В `db.php` в строке 20 отсутствует точка с запятой.
2. В том же файле, в функции используется переменная `$conn` из глобального пространства имен.

   ```
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
   $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   function selectContent($url){   
       $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE url='$url'");  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       $result_page = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       return $result_page;
   }
   ```

Надо либо передавать ее внутрь функции, либо объявлять внутри, либо использовать `global` (фу-фу-фу!)

После исправления этих двух ошибок у меня на машине все отработало без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Если `$db` это `\PDO`, то лучше так:

```
function Content($url){
    $stmt =$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE url=:url');
    $stmt->execute(array(':url' => $url));
    $result_page = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result_page;
}
```